# Wrong calcuation of event.balance value in reminder email

Tags: civievent

A client is reporting that the value for the `{event.balance}` token sent via a reminder is incorrect. It's showing a negative balance. The two documented cases (via forwarded emails from the event registrants) were both case where one partial payment had been made.

The replacement for `{event.balance}` should be:

```
Total registration fees minus partial payment(s)
```

Instead the token was replaced with the following value:

```
Event balance minus partial payment
```

Any ideas about what might be causing this or how to troubleshoot it?

Site running CiviCRM 4.5.8 and Drupal 7.36. PHP is 5.4.30. MySQL is 5.5.42

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible this is the culprit: [net amount sometimes incorrect for events involving partial payments](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16175)

You could update to 4.6.2 if that's possible, or perhaps [review out the commit](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/5588) and roll your own patch.